# Paypal Mass Pay API Response Handling

Tags: paypal, masspay

So this is probably more of a discussion item so I apologise if this should go elsewhere.

But I need to handle Responses (IPN) from using Paypal MassPay API.

At the moment I'm handling the Notifications correctly and tracking past payments made (Royalty Payments System).

**Problem 1: Unclaimed Payments**

But I've encountered an issue which I can't seem to handle on the sandbox site and that is Unclaimed payments. Now according to MassPay guide:

> If the recipients do not have PayPal accounts, PayPal notifies them that a payment is available and they must create a PayPal account to receive the payment.

I assume this means that Paypal sends the user an email, I tried to test this but I received no notification

**Problem 2: Claiming unclaimed Payments**

Following the previous problem, I've been unable to test users claiming unclaimed values. So I'm wondering does anybody know how Paypal processes these and the format of the response;

1. Does the response contain all previously claimed payments?
2. Does the response contain all unclaimed payments?
3. Does the response contain the status of all transfers in that transaction?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

When you send out your MassPay request, any unclaimed payments will be pending until they're claimed.  Your IPN will show "processed" instead of "completed" for the status.  Once they claim the payment you will get another IPN showing the payment has been completed.

When working in the sandbox you won't get any actual emails from their system.  All test emails show up in your developer.paypal.com account under the test email section there.

Comment: Cheers for the info on the test email. But it still doesn't help me with the testing the process of "Claiming UnClaimed funds". As far as I can tell there is currently no way to claim the unclaimed funds in the sandbox environment

Comment: You could log in to the sandbox seller account, click into Fraud Management Filters, and set the option to Review all payments over a certain amount.  Just set it to $1 and send it more than that.  This will trigger the unclaimed payment which the person would then have to review and claim.  This should allow you to test that process on the sandbox.

Comment: Or you could send a mass payment to a specific (nonexistent) address and then manually create an account with the same address via https://developer.paypal.com/ > Test accounts > Create account: manual. The (received) mass payment should be visible in the transaction history within the next couple of minutes.

Comment: Thanks for the advise robert but Paypal seems to append random characters to the end of create email accounts. @AndrewAngell cheers I will give that a go